# Choose glyphs for webfont

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts

I am using a font to build a website. The design uses a font that has several glyphs for the same letter "a" and I need to use a specific one.
The issue I have is to choose between the two once the font has been converted to a webfont. Is this possible and how can I choose what glyp to use in the webfont?
Here is what both glyphs look like :

[image: Two different glyps for the same letter]

The font I am using is [andes condensed](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/andes-condensed/webfont_preview.html) and I am using [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate the webfont.

Comment: Generally speaking, a one story "a" is an italic style whereas the two story one is found in most roman style faces. There's no rule, per se.

Comment: @Stan This is about alternates within the same style, not variants across styles. Andes roman has (IIRC) a two-storey a as its standard, but the single-storey ɑ is available as a stylistic alternate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the glyphs through the OpenType feature they were added to. For this font it seems to be ss01 (Stylistic set 1). So you don’t use a different character/Unicode value, you just apply a different CSS styling which calls the OpenType feature. And make sure the glyphs don’t get removed through the subsetting. 
And just a word of warning: The majority of commercial fonts do not allow font modifications. Using the Fontsquirrel generator would count as that. Ask the foundry or the vendor where you bought it if you are unsure.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I'll check out the if I can modify this font.  For other people with the same issue as me the *CSS* property to change the font glyphs (and other things) is `font-feature-settings` more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a one story "a" as your example on the left is an italic style whereas the two story one on the right is found in most roman style faces. There's no rule, per se.

Why the two? Sometimes, a "slanted" font can be made to imitate a roman face so the glyph you might choose would be the first example if you wanted to do that. Maybe there is no italic style for that typeface. These are called faux italics. A true italic face is not a simple slanted roman face. It is a special variation of the roman face in the same family of typefaces. Ideally, you do not slant a roman face; but, choose a family with a proper italic style included.